# Why would String(contentsOfFile) fail even though the file exists?

Tags: string, swift, file-io

In the below code, I am trying to access a file `0.txt` located in my home directory. The path to the home directory is saved within a string and the name `0.txt` is appended to it upon call (`0` is  a reference counter which will change values as the program runs. For the sake of the question, I'll refer to it as `0`).

```
func loadfile(counter: Int) -> String {     // counter here is assumed to be "0"
    var contents = String()
    var defaultpath = ("~/" as NSString).stringByExpandingTildeInPath as String
    do {
        contents = try String(contentsOfFile: defaultpath.stringByAppendingString(String("\(counter).txt")))
        return contents
    } catch {
        print("For some reason, the file couldn't be accessed.")
        return "failed"
    }
}
```

However, every time this block of code runs, the return value is `failed` and the line `For some reason, the file couldn't be accessed` is printed, even though `~/0.txt` exists. Does anyone have an idea as to why this abnormal behavior is occurring, and if so, how should I resolve this issue??

<sub>*Side question: is there a way to print the errors generated by the try-catch block to stdout?*</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a separator to the filename:

```
contents = try String(contentsOfFile: defaultpath.stringByAppendingString(String("/\(counter).txt")))
```

Note the forward slash at the beginning of the filename.  The `defaultPath` does not end with a slash.

Comment: *gasp* how did I miss that trailing slash... Thank you. By any chance would you know how I can print the errors generated as well?

Comment: That should probably be a separate question.  But here's a working example from a playground:  `do {
    let str = try NSString(contentsOfFile: "Foo.bar",
                           encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}`